# Schitt’s Creek David Ring Combination

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutation

So I’ve been trying to figure this one out. On Schitt’s Creek, David wears various combinations of rings. He has four rings and he can arrange them on his ten fingers in various ways - each ring is exactly the same and indistinguishable from the rest. Both of his thumbs can have one ring max, and each of the other fingers can have two rings max. What are the total number of ways that the rings can be distributed. Or another way, what is the probability for any given arrangement of all four rings under these conditions?

Edit: I mistyped sadly. I mean the non-thumb fingers can have two rings max per finger.

Comment: Considering a non-thumb finger, is the event of having one ring on the finger the same or are there different positions on the same finger a ring can occupy when only one ring is on the finger? (ie above or below knuckle)

Comment: There are two possible positions for each non-thumb fingers - one above the knuckle and one below the knuckle.

Comment: Is the 2nd position (above the knuckle) on each non-thumb finger ok to pick when there is no ring in the first position (below knuckle)?  If it is OK to pick position 2, then the answer is just 18 choose 4 (or 3,060).  But if the 1st has to be picked in order to use the 2nd it's more complicated (fewer possibilities)!

Comment: Yes! There is no need to fill the below-knuckle position in order to fill the above-knuckle positions. Thanks for the help!